Changing keyboard layout to numapd for numeric fields on Ubuntu Frame Onscreen Keyboard
I have a kiosk machine (touchscreen only) running Ubuntu Frame on Ubuntu Server. On it I have a Mir Kiosk browser pointed to my web application (running locally). I have the Ubuntu Frame OSK (Onscreen Keyboard) set up.
I have a page with some text inputs and some numeric inputs. For numeric inputs I use a component called MudNumericField, ultimately what it does is generate an  element with a property of inputmode="numeric".
I need the keyboard to change its layout based on the context. If I select a normal text field, I want the full keyboard. If I select a numeric field, I just want a numpad. (this is something that works out of the box on Windows). Is it possible to setup the keyboard in this way?
Bonus question: After setting one of the fields to numeric, I noticed something in the system has proactively added an input validator.

(sorry about the shoddy picture quality)
I don't want this validator, as I have my own validators with custom logic (and this one doesn't match my UI look, or even the language). How do I get rid of it?
